# How to get the email id of a contact of profile of an account to which the current contact is associated?

Tags: apex

User is deleting a contact . If user profile is A , then a mail should be sent to a contact of profile ABCD  who is also part of the same account as the contact.

```
Contact currentContact = [select accountid from contact where id =: contactId];
    for(Contact c: [Select Id, email, owner.email from Contact where Accountid = :currentContact.accountid and owner.profileID = 'SASASASA' ])
    {
        emailTo.add(c.email);
    }
```

Above is the code written to fetch the email id of contact with profile ABCD. 
Is there a way to get the email id of the contact with profile ABCD  and not the contact owner with profile ABCD ?

Comment: Profile can have many users and each user can have contact. So how are you associating Contact with Profile?

Comment: @Ashwani So the requirement is like - if any of the contact in that account has profile ABCD , collect the email id and send a mail . Is that feasible?

Comment: @Ashwani -  
If I need to address that contact(whose user has profile 'ABCD' and also part of account which the contact is being deleted) in my email template . Is that doable? as in,  in place of Dear {!Contact.FirstName} , I want to address the user to which the mail is being sent .

Comment: If template is referencing {!Contact.FirstName}, you can not use {!User.Name}

Comment: @Ashwani - Yes ..so is it feasible that I can use any tag  to indicate the user with profile X of the account whose contact is being deactivated? Example - once the  contact is deactivated , a mail should be sent to the contact of the same account whose user is having profile X - saying Hello (Name of user with profile X )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want to do this:

```
Contact currentContact = [select accountid from contact where id =: contactId];

for(User u: [Select Id, Contact.email, Contact.Owner.email FROM User WHERE profile.ID = 'SASASASA' AND Contact.accountid=currentContact.accountid])
{
        emailTo.add(u.contact.email);
}
```

Sending email to all contacts whose user has profile 'ABCD' and also part of account which the contact is being deleted.

Comment: It worked :) Furthermore , I need to address that contact(whose user has profile 'ABCD' and also part of account which the contact is being deleted) in my email template . Is that doable? as in in place of Dear {!Contact.FirstName}